# FLWOR in MarkLogic 9 does not show results in chrome

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-9

Hello I am using MarkLogic 9 and trying to build an app with XQuery together with the FLWOR statements. I setup the http server. I tested a simple page with static text on port 8031 which works fine. I also tested a 
FLWOR statement in the query console which also works fine. But when I combine it, it does not work.

I hope you can help me out.

Manny thanks

Erik

**FLOWER STATEMENT ML 9.0**

```
for $i in /scope/item
let $sscc := $i/transaction/sscc/text()
return <tr><td>{$sscc}</td></tr>
```

**TEST.XQY**

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
xdmp:set-response-content-type("text/html; charset=utf-8"),
'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">',
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Find my orders</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr><th>SSCC</th></tr>
      {
        for $i in /scope/item
        let $sscc := $i/transaction/sscc/text()
        return <tr><td>{$sscc}</td></tr>
      }
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

**HTTP APPLICATION PAGE**
[image]

**XML SOURCE FILE**

```
<scope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <item>
        <transaction>
            <type>CI</type>
            <sscc>00000379471900000025</sscc>
            <location>4260210630688</location>
            <device>VISTALINK.004</device>
            <date>2017-04-25</date>
            <time>02:15:33</time>
            <gmtOffset>+02:00</gmtOffset>
            <actorId>155081</actorId>
        </transaction>
        <order>
            <orderNumber>3794719</orderNumber>
        </order>
        <load>
            <rti>
                <ean>8714548186004</ean>
                <grai>8003087145481860040019877322</grai>
                <column>2</column>
                <size>
                    <width>1900</width>
                    <height>95</height>
                    <depth>0</depth>
                </size>
                <position>
                    <x>2062,48707520218</x>
                    <y>2015,24337520512</y>
                    <z>0</z>
                </position>
            </rti>
            <rti>
                <ean>8714548106002</ean>
                <grai>8003087145481060020016434653</grai>
                <column>0</column>
                <size>
                    <width>1900</width>
                    <height>95</height>
                    <depth>0</depth>
                </size>
                <position/>
            </rti>
            <rti>
                <ean>8714548186004</ean>
                <grai>8003087145481860040012803719</grai>
                <column>2</column>
                <size>
                    <width>1900</width>
                    <height>95</height>
                    <depth>0</depth>
                </size>
                <position>
                    <x>2064,20629390666</x>
                    <y>2124,57539157396</y>
                    <z>0</z>
                </position>
            </rti>
            <rti>...</rti>
            <rti>...</rti>
            <rti>...</rti>
            <rti>...</rti>
            <rti>...</rti>
        </load>
    </item>
</scope>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to mention some exact details about the results you did get, but looking at your code, I'm guessing, your HTML page does show, but without the expected rows. That is probably due to namespaces.

You have embedded your FLWOR statement inside literal XHTML. That is normally just fine, but since your XHTML carries a default namespace declaration, XPath expressions contained in that same XML will get interpreted with that same namespace declaration. This mean an XPath expression like `/scope/item` is actually interpreted as `/xhtml:scope/xhtml:item` in your case.

Simplest way out is to grab the items upfront, and/or use wildcard prefixes. Perhaps something like:

```
let $items := fn:collection()/scope/item
return
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title>Find my orders</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <table>
        <tr><th>SSCC</th></tr>
        {
          for $i in $items
          let $sscc := $i/*:transaction/*:sscc/text()
          return <tr><td>{$sscc}</td></tr>
        }
      </table>
    </body>
  </html>
```

HTH!

Comment: Thanks, this helps me a lot

Comment: grtjn, do you how to handle nesting with a flower statement ?